# BASIC PHP - MYSQL Query - Form will not submit, Just refreshes

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm designing an online Role-Playing Game, (Gangster Themed)...
I've been working on a Hit-list page for some time now, but still can't get my head around this no matter how much I try...

Basically the `form` I'm using will not submit and update the `database` at all, it just refreshes upon submitting with no error message or anything at all, I would be grateful for some help with this, as it's beginning to rack my brain now...

I will post my pages code below so you will be able to get a jist of what is going on here. (Also will link to a text file on my website containing the full page of `PHP & SQL & & Javascript & HTML` code...

[Click here for the link to the pages full code including HTML & Form...](http://mobcity.co.uk/help.txt)

```
<?php

///// START OF DEFAULTS /////

session_start();
include "include/connect.php";
include "include/require.php";
include_once("include/time.php");
logincheck();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$dateetime = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()+60*60);
$fetch=mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username='$username'"));
$view=$_GET['view'];
$select=$_POST['select'];

///// END OF DEFAULTS /////

?>

<?php

///// START OF HITLISTING USERS /////

if ($_POST['submit']){
    $target=addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['target'])); 
    $reward=addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['reward']));
    $reason=addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['reason']));
    $total_cost=intval(strip_tags($_POST['total_cost']));
    if ($select == "1"){
        if ($total_cost > "0"){
            if ($total_cost == 0 || !$total_cost || ereg('[^0-9]',$total_cost)){
                print "<table border='0' bordercolor='black' align='center' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr><td class='notice' align='center'><font color='#CAO300'>You have entered an invalid value!</td>
        </tr>
        </table><br>";
            }elseif ($total_cost != 0 && $total_cost && !ereg('[^0-9]',$total_cost)){
                if ($total_cost > $fetch->money){
                    echo "<table border='0' bordercolor='black' align='center' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr><td class='notice' align='center'><font color='#CAO300'>You do not have money to payout that reward!</td>
        </tr>
        </table><br>";
                }elseif ($total_cost <= $fetch->money){
                    $user_loose = $fetch->money - $total_cost;
                    $bank_add = $total_cost;
                    mysql_query("UPDATE user_info SET money=money-$total_cost WHERE username='$username'");
                    mysql_query("UPDATE hitlist_first SET reward=reward+$reward && hits=hits+1 && buy_off=buy_off+$total_cost WHERE target='$target'");
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `hitlist_second` ( `id` , `posted_by` , `anonymous` , `reason` , `reward` , `target` ) 
    VALUES ('', '$username', 'No', '$reason', '$reward', '$target')");
                    echo "<table border='0' bordercolor='black' align='center' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr><td class='notice' align='center'><font color='#2FB600'>You have successfully Hitlisted $target!</td>
        </tr>
        </table><br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}elseif ($select == "2"){
    if ($total_cost > "0"){
        if ($total_cost == 0 || !$total_cost || ereg('[^0-9]',$total_cost)){
            print "<table border='0' bordercolor='black' align='center' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr><td class='notice' align='center'><font color='#CAO300'>You have entered an invalid value!</td>
        </tr>
        </table><br>";
        }elseif ($total_cost != 0 || $total_cost || !ereg('[^0-9]',$total_cost)){
            if ($total_cost > $fetch->money){ echo "<table border='0' bordercolor='black' align='center' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr><td class='notice' align='center'><font color='#CAO300'>You do not have money to payout that reward!</td>
        </tr>
        </table><br>"; }elseif ($total_cost <= $fetch->money){
                $user_loose = $fetch->money - $total_cost;
                $bank_add = $total_cost;
                mysql_query("UPDATE user_info SET money=money-$total_cost WHERE username='$username'");
                mysql_query("UPDATE hitlist_first SET reward=reward+$reward && hits=hits+1 && buy_off=buy_off+$total_cost WHERE target='$target'");
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO `hitlist_second` ( `id` , `posted_by` , `anonymous` , `reason` , `reward` , `target` ) 
    VALUES ('', '$username', 'Yes', '$reason', '$reward', '$target')");
                echo "<table border='0' bordercolor='black' align='center' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr><td class='notice' align='center'><font color='#2FB600'>You have successfully Hitlisted $target!</td>
        </tr>
        </table><br>";
            }
        }
    }
}

///// END OF HITLISTING USERS /////

?>
```

Comment: please format your code, ditch mysql_* and come back to use if it still fails

Comment: The `ereg()` functions are deprecated, you should be using `preg_match()`.

Comment: You just assume that all your sql statements are correct, but you do not bother to check if they raise any errors or get executed at all.

Comment: Does the form have a submit button with `name="submit"`?

Comment: You do `$total_cost=intval(...)`. Why do you then need to check `ereg('[^0-9]', $total_cost)`? `intval()` can never return anything else.

Comment: `elseif ($select == "2")` matches with `if ($_POST['submit'])`. Shouldn't it be linked with `if ($select == "1")`?

Comment: @Barmar you can make an article about it

Comment: I am fairly new to all of this, I'm still in early learning stages but am wanting to further my knowledge in this sector, I have tried updating my code using the advice given above, however I have still gotten no further with my issue...

Answer (score 0):

you have : `<input type="hidden" name="select" id="select" value="0">` 
so your variable $select should be "0"
you only have `if($select == "1")` and `if($select == "2")` 
there's no `if($select == "0")` that's why it doesn't do anything

Comment: Thankyou, your answer was very useful, I have now added if($select == "0") however, now even if an option is selected it just returns the error message from if($select == "0") as if to say there has been no option selected...